# How to directly access a python method in kanban view templates in Odoo 12?

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I have a kanban view with a template in **Odoo 12** and I need to access a python method data there to print them in a table. My python method returns a dictionary of key-value pairs.

I used **t-foreach** as below:

```
<t t-foreach="get_departments()" t-as="item">
    <tr>
        <td class="text-right">
            <t t-esc="item"/>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <t t-esc="item_value"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</t>
```

And this is the method in my model:

```
def get_departments(self):
        dep_patients = {}
        departments = self.env['hr.department'].search([('patient_depatment', '=', True)])
        appointment = self.env['hms.appointment'].search([])
        for dept in departments:
            couter = 0
            for app in appointment:
                if dept.id == app.department_id.id:
                    couter +=1
            dep_patients.update({dept.name: couter})

        return dep_patients
```

in my template, on method call upon page loading I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: QWeb2 - template['kanban-box']: Runtime Error: TypeError: dict.get_departments is not a function
http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3374
Traceback:
Error: QWeb2 - template['kanban-box']: Runtime Error: TypeError: dict.get_departments is not a function
    at Object.exception (http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3374:7)
    at Engine.eval (eval at _render (http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3416:73), <anonymous>:114:29)
    at Engine._render (http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3415:296)
    at Engine.render (http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3415:151)
    at Engine._render (http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3419:57)
    at Engine.render (http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3415:151)
    at Class._render (http://localhost:8000/web/content/901-66db042/web.assets_backend.js:1804:451)
    at Class.start (http://localhost:8000/web/content/901-66db042/web.assets_backend.js:1794:1256)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as start] (http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3538:488)
    at http://localhost:8000/web/content/862-f2fdf49/web.assets_common.js:3683:52
```

As the error shows it seems that my python method is not accessible in the template and I may need to define a JavaScript method for accessing python method data in this case. Is there any way to directly access my python method in a template of Kanban view or not? if yes, how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that you can call a function in QWeb report.

```
    <t t-set="result" t-value="o.call_some_method()"/>
```

But I think you cannot do that in Kanban view because, you cannot access
the `RecordSet` by any variable it's in the client side and calling a function
it's not simple as that it's an rcp call as I remember.

But you can work arround this by using a `computed field` like in Odoo account module (odoo 10.0).

```py
   department_list = fields.Text('Departments', compute='get_departments')



   @api.one
   def get_departments(self):
       """ use SQL to enhance performance."""
       dep_patients  = []
       computing_sql = """
            SELECT
                 hp.departement_id,
                 hd.name,
                 count(*) as appointment_count
            FROM 
                  hr_department hd 

            INNER JOIN hms_appointment hp on hd.id hp.departement_id

            WHERE
                 hd.patient_depatment is True
            GROUP BY departement_id, hd.name
            """
        self.env.cr.execute(computing_sql)
        for dp_id, dp_name, counts in self.env.cr.fetchall():
           # add an dict to use it as a json object later in javascript
           dep_patients.append({'name':dp_name, 'count': counts})

        self.department_list = json.dumps(dep_patients) if dep_patients else False
```

and in your view just do

```xml
   <t t-value="JSON.parse(record.department_list.raw_value)" t-set="department_list"/>

   <t t-foreach="department_list" t-as="item">
        <!-- here item is an json object with two attributes name, count -->
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right">
                <t t-esc="item.name"/>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <t t-esc="tem.count"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </t>
```

Sorry for syntax errors Hope you get the idea, you can check this in account model of odoo

Comment: This solution worked for me and I accessed the method returned data in Kanban view template. I just wonder to know does json.dump is related to javascript part of Odoo or not?

Comment: Odoo uses Third party libraries - like backbone, underscooreJs among others.